# How to use BLOB data type with different databases in flyway?

Tags: database, migration, blob, flyway

is it possible to use only one SQL-Script to create this table with BLOB data type in mssyl, mysql and oracle in FLYWAY?

```
CREATE TABLE TFILEATTACHMENT (
  ATTACHID decimal(16,0) NOT NULL,
  FILENAME varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  FILEBLOB blob,
  USERID varchar(10) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (ATTACHID)
);
```

A flyway migration works fine with this script under MYSQL and ORACLE. But MSSQL does not know the data type "blob" - so we use the type "VARBINARY" in mssql.
But it would be nice when we have only one script for all databases.

Is it possible that flyway handle this db specific translation from blob to e.g. varbinary?
Or is there a better "standard"-SQL datatype then "blob"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to solve this is to use **placeholders**. You can then define a placeholder **`${blobDataType}`** containing either the value *`FILEBLOB`* or the value *`VARBINARY`* depending on the **configuration** of your current environment.

Comment: Thank you very much for this advice. Placeholders are a great concept. Do you think that placeholders are also a good solution for the "GO" statements in MSSQL after table creates?